# Counting occurrences of arrays of numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, compare

How do you count the number of occurrences of number arrays in plain Javascript? Where something like this (imagine having hundreds to these number sets):

```
[2, 5, 66, 199]
[32, 56, 88, 109]
[13, 45, 102, 200]
[2, 5, 66, 199]
[2, 5, 66, 199]
[32, 56, 88, 109]
```

would give me back something like this:

```
2, 5, 66, 199 -> 3 times
32, 56, 88, 109 -> 2 times
13, 45, 102, 200 -> 1 time
```

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Comment: Are they always in the same order or is `[1,2,3]` equivalent to `[3,2,1]`

Comment: @Jamiec 95% of the time yes, but there's a possibility that they may fall out of sequence

Comment: protip: 95% of the time might as well be 0% of the time. You're going to have to deal with it even if it is only 0.00000001% of the time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create string from array and use it as key in object. If you want `[1, 2] != [2, 1]` just remove `sort` before `join` method.

```js
const data = [[2, 5, 66, 199],[32, 56, 88, 109],[13, 45, 102, 200],[2, 5, 66, 199],[2, 5, 66, 199],[32, 56, 88, 109]]
const result = data.reduce((r, e) => {
  const arr = e.sort().join(',');
  r[arr] = (r[arr] || 0) + 1;
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks Nenad, that's what I was looking for.